# BlueStacks giving me an object reference error after a possibly messy reinstall

Tags: installation, bluestacks

I installed the latest BlueStacks 2 version, but it got stuck on the init screen, so I:

- Killed its processes.
- Deleted the BlueStacks folders.
- Deleted BlueStacks from register(?).
- Reinstalled and tried to give it as much control over its folder as possible.

Of course it gives me another error:

> Object reference not set to instance of an object.

Frustratingly non specific, yeah?
Anyone who can help?

Comment: Or even how I can look into the problem further than "somehow, somewhere, there was a failed object reference".

Comment: You may need to be a local administrator on your machine if you're running it on Windows or else run it as an administator. We had a developer that needed to have this on some PCs for non-local admins and I had to create a domain service account to use as a proxy to set as a local administrator and then use a saved credential for the shortcut icon for that to work on those machines.Here's [My Posted Answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/734320/allow-standard-user-to-run-program-as-local-admin-without-elevation-prompt/734360#734360) on this topic from Server Fault. Just a thought though.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have Bluestacks 2 installed but the error of (object reference not set shows up after you double click the Bluestacks file) then this is what you should do.

Had the same problem and what I diagnosed is that the problem has something to do with Bluestacks screen resolution.

What I want you to do is change or rather reduce your screen resolution to lets say 800x600 then open Bluestacks.

Once it does open change back to the original resolution.
Lemme know how it works out. :D

Answer (score 0):

That error seems to happen if the BlueStacks registry settings for its window size somehow got changed to an invalid value like 0 or -1, possibly due to a bug with BlueStacks. You must edit the following registry values (the window resolution of BlueStacks) to valid values using the Registry Editor (regedit.exe):

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\BlueStacks\Guests\Android\FrameBuffer\0\WindowWidth
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\BlueStacks\Guests\Android\FrameBuffer\0\WindowHeight

Or (easier) use the following registry file (copy the following text in code markup and save it to a .REG file using a text editor):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
; Fix for BlueStacks errors: http://superuser.com/a/1078513/10259?bluestacks-giving-me-an-object-reference-error

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\BlueStacks\Guests\Android\FrameBuffer\0]
"WindowWidth"=dword:00000500
"WindowHeight"=dword:000002d0
```

This registry file sets the size of the BlueStacks window to 1280 × 720. I made it as the error regularly happens to my copy of BlueStacks. Just open up the resulting .REG file and allow the Registry Editor to make the changes. Aside from the 'Object reference not set to instance of an object' error, this should also help fix the following errors:

- Error: parameter is not valid
- Error: InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index
- Error: Rectangle '{X=0,Y=0/Width=60,Height=0}' cannot have a width or height equal to 0.
- Error: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: MinimumSize